# Re-exporting modules does not work with object spread

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, export, es6-modules

i have an `index.js` file that reads:

```
import aReducer from './ducks/a';
import bReducer from './ducks/b';
import * as aSelectors from './ducks/a';
import * as bSelectors from './ducks/b';

console.log(aReducer) //function i expect
console.log(aSelectors) //object with keys to selectors i expect

export { aReducer, bReducer, ...aSelectors, ...bSelectors };
```

If I `console.log` in this file I see that the reducers are functions I expect and the selectors alias are objects with keys to the selectors I expect. The reducers are default exports for the duck files and the selectors are exports from the same respective file.

However, when I try to import this module with another file I am only able to import the two reducers. The two selectors are undefined. I thought that de-structuring would add each key to my export object. What am I doing wrong?

`other_file1.js`

```
import { aReducer, bReducer } from 'my-module'; //works!
```

`other_file2.js`

```
import { someSelectorThatWasInMyaSelectorsObject } from 'my-module'; //does NOT work!
```

Comment: You can't use `...` in an `export {};` statement. Is that not giving you a syntax error?

Comment: nope, no error there - isn't it just exporting an object? We can use `...` in objects.

Comment: Weird. What are you using to handle your module processing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `...` in an `export {};` block. It is an explicit list of names just like `import  {name} from` is. It is not an object with keys being exported. e.g. the same way imports do

```
import { foo as fooRenamed } from "";
```

with `export` it is

```
export {
  fooVar as foo,
};
```

The `export` block is an explicit list of variables to export, with an optional explicit name for the export. There are no objects involved.

Specifically, there are no objects involved because the names of the exports are processed and known before the body of the file has even executed, so not only are objects not allowed, they are impossible to allow because objects require execution to exist.

To get what you'd want, you should use:

```
// Export the referenced files' default under two specific names.
export { default as aReducer } from './ducks/a';
export { default as bReducer } from './ducks/b';

// Re-export every named export from these two files.
export * from './ducks/a';
export * from './ducks/b';
```

Comment: Thanks for the write out. I just tried this but I still have the same problem. :( I'm able to see the reducers but any selectors are `undefined` when importing them in other files.

Comment: It's possible you have other issues, I'm not sure that I can add more without a full working example unfortunately. One common cause of unexpected `undefined` values for imports is that there could be circular dependencies, so when you try to reference the imported value, it hasn't been assigned yet, but I can't say if that is an issue from just the snippets given.

Comment: you know what - after trying to add more code and write out my directory structure for this question, I realized I was testing the wrong selector so of course that is undefined. You implementation works - thanks!

Comment: This is unfortunate because instead of being able to have a single entry point, you either have to reference the resource directly or redundantly repeat function and/or variable references in the index as well. For e.g. module.exports with the spread destructuring was great for having one /index.js entry point for action type constants, actions, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `export * from` doesn't repeat names, and `export {default as X} from` is needed because it never had a name in the first place.